# java.util.Observable does not follow GoF's observer design pattern, right?

Tags: java, observer-pattern, design-patterns

If I understand correctly, in the  observer design pattern, a concrete observer has the concrete subjet as a field.  This is as illustrated in GoF's book:

[image]

On the other hand,  in the implementation of `notifyObserver(Object arg)` of `java.util.Observable` , the subject is passed again to the observer (See [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Observable.java#132) )

[image]

If the concrete subject is supposed to be referable through a field in the concrete observer (as in the GoF's spec), why are we sending the concrete subject again to the observer (as in `java.util.observable` code) This seems to suggest me that `java.util.Observable` does not follow the GoF's spec. Have I misunderstood something here? Thanks.

Comment: A pattern is just that: a pattern, it doesn't actually proscribe a concrete implementation.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. So you have confirmed me that java.util.Observable does not follow GoF's spec, haven't you?

Comment: @zell Please go through the intro and initial chapters of GoF again to gain better understanding "what is a design pattern" before proceeding to the actual details of the various patterns, this understanding is absolutely essential for any programmer !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the implementations differ.

BUT!

The pattern is the concept, not the implementation. And the concept is the same. In both cases the observer has a reference to the observed item, but you could definitely also imagine a situation where the observer does not need this reference at all.

So the concept here is "Something gets notified when something else changes state or executes in some way", and it's much broader than any of the implementations.